# Classifying the row by price (may need to use the explict cursor)

Tags: plsql

I need to classify the product name by price. This below is what I made so far.

Do I need to finish the last one as `cursor c1(Price_A Number) is select Product_A, Status_A from Product`?

Honestly, I could not get it at all. Can anybody help me for this question please?

[image]

Here is what I wrote so far:

```
Declare 
  Product_A Product.product_Name%type; 
  Price_A Product.Price%type; 
  Status_A Varchar(20); 
  cursor c1(Price_A Number) 
   is select Product_A, Status_A from Product
  ;
begin
  'nothing
end;
```

Comment: Declare
 Product_A Product.product_Name%type;
 Price_A Product.Price%type;
 Status_A Varchar(20);
 cursor c1(Price_A Number) is select

Comment: It said that my coding is not proper format....

Comment: Why do you think you need an explicit cursor? You don't - an ordinary `for r in (select...) loop` will do it. Within the loop you just need a `dbms_output` statement with a `case` or `if` expression. When you post questions on SO you need to include the exact code that isn't working and the exact error message, not just a photo of your homework assignment.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to do it with explicit cursor and SQL case in the cursor:

```
Declare 
  Product_A Product.product_Name%type; 
  Price_A Product.Price%type; 
  Status_A Varchar(20); 
  cursor c1 is
   select product_name, price
     , case 
          when price < 5 then 'low' 
          when price between 5 and 20 then 'medium' 
          else 'high' -- price >20
       end status
   from product;
begin
  open c1;
  loop
    fetch c1 into Product_A, Price_A, Status_A;
    exit when c1%NOTFOUND;
    dbms_output.put_line(rpad(Product_A, 15)|| rpad(Price_A, 5)|| Status_A);
  end loop;
end;
/
```

But its simpler with implicit cursor: no declaration needed:

```
begin
  for x in (
       select product_name, price
     , case 
          when price < 5 then 'low' 
          when price between 5 and 20 then 'medium' 
          else 'high' -- price >20
       end status
   from product) loop
    dbms_output.put_line(rpad(x.Product_Name, 15)|| rpad(x.price, 5)|| x.status);
  end loop;
end;
/
```

## input data to test it:

```
create table product (product_Name varchar2(15), price number);

insert into product
          select 'a', 3 from dual
union all select 'b', 13 from dual
union all select 'bb', 20 from dual
union all select 'c', 130 from dual
;
```